# coding the IF-ELSE of Fuzzy Logic in a microcontroller

Tags: c, microcontroller, fuzzy-logic

I have this project where I want to try putting fuzzy logic in a PIC microcontroller, and well, at the If-else part. I was wondering if it would be better to:

Hard code `if-else`and then just look for the appropriate value later i.e.:

```
if(DSSD == MTC and RV == CF){
        ACC = SD;
    }
else if(DSSD == MTC and RV == CL){
        ACC = SL;
    }
```

Or do I iterate `for` so that as you scan through the members, then you could easily min-max for the output value?

```
       /* process if-side of rule to determine strength */
  for(ip=rule->if_side; ip != NULL; ip=ip->next)
      strength = min(strength,*(ip->value));
       /* process then-side of rule to apply strength */
  for(tp=rule->then_side; tp != NULL; tp=tp->next)
      *(tp->value) = max(strength,*(tp->value));
```

I was wondering on the speed, code density, and code complexity pros and cons.